# Can you generate sine wave data continuously from an Angular service and inject it into a component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component which has an injected service to retrieve static mock data. I would like to add the ability to generate data at a variable frequency and send the new (appended, time series) data to the component as it is generated.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this.

All I know for sure is that the data object for the component must be immutable.

Any points in the right direction would be appreciated. I thought maybe I needed a service worker at one point, but that seem's a bit overkill for a mock up. Eventually, this service will actually use streams to connect to a data source over the internet, but until that day I want to be able to pretend as if there is a stream of data coming from the service to the component for UI development/prototyping.

**plotter.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MockDataService } from '../../services/mock-data/mock-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plotter',
  templateUrl: './plotter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plotter.component.css']
})
export class PlotterComponent implements OnInit {

  single: any[];
  multi: any[];

  // rt needs to be an immutable object array
  // rt needs to be updated with data from MockDataService
  rt: any[];

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Country';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Population';

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

  constructor(private mockDataService: MockDataService) {
    // Object.assign(this, { single, multi });
    this.single = mockDataService.getSingle();
    this.multi = mockDataService.getMulti();
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

**mock-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { single, multi } from '../../mock-data/plot-data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MockDataService {

  constructor() { }

  getSingle() {
    return single;
  }

  getMulti() {
    return multi;
  }

  // Generate sine wave data here
  sineWave(pAmplitude, pFrequency) {

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to put your arrays in a Subject or BehaviorSubject. Then return this as an Observable and subscribe to it. As soon as you now change the value of one of them by using the setter in the service, your component's copy of the arrays gets automatically updated.

**plotter.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MockDataService } from '../../services/mock-data/mock-data.service';
import { timer, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plotter',
  templateUrl: './plotter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plotter.component.css']
})
export class PlotterComponent implements OnInit {
  /*
   timer takes a second argument, how often to emit subsequent values
   in this case it will call the method for the first time after 1 second and
   subsequent calls follow every 10 seconds after
  */
  const source = timer(1000, 10000);
  let subscription: Subscription;

  single: any[];
  multi: any[];

  pAmplitude: number = 0;
  pFrequency: number = 0;

  // rt needs to be an immutable object array
  // rt needs to be updated with data from MockDataService
  rt: any[];

  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'Country';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'Population';

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

  constructor(private mockDataService: MockDataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.mockDataService.getSingle().subscribe( data => {
          this.single = data;
      });

      this.mockDataService.getMulti().subscribe( data => {
          this.multi = data;
      });

      this.startPolling();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  startPolling(): void {
      this.subscription = source.subscribe(
          () => {
                  // increase the value of both variables then
                  // call the method in the service and hand in the variables
                  this.pFrequency += 12;
                  this.pAmplitude += 24;
                  this.mockDataService.sineWave(this.pAmplitude, this.pFrequency); 
                }
      );
  }

  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

**mock-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { single, multi } from '../../mock-data/plot-data';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MockDataService {

  private single: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private multi: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor() { 
  }

  getSingle(): Observable<any[]> {
    return single.asObservable();
  }

  setSingle(data: any[]): void {
      this.single.next(data);
  }

  getMulti(): Observable<any[]> {
    return multi.asObservable();
  }

  setMulti(data: any[]): void {
      this.multi.next(data);
  }

  // Generate sine wave data here
  sineWave(pAmplitude, pFrequency) {
      console.log('set new pAmplitude: ', pAmplitude);
      console.log('set new pFrequency: ', pFrequency);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem or answered your question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was actually sort of on this path while I was waiting for a reply. So can I run the sinWave function in a loop of some sort (this I am still confused on) and have it use the set functions to add the new points to the arrays?

Upon further thought.. perhaps I need to generate the sine wave in another component that communicates to the plotter and has the mock-data.service injected in it?

Comment: Here you go. I updated the answer. Please have a look at the `timer` I added. The current configuration says, that it starts after 1 second and calls `sinWave()`. Then this call gets repeated every 10 seconds until `ngOnDestroy()` gets called. The whole mechanism is started in `ngOnInit()` via `this.startPolling();`. --- To your second question: Inside the service you don't have to use the setter. You can directly use `multi.next()` or `single.next()`. -- Hope this helps.

Comment: PS: The question who sets the values can only be answered by yourself as I don‘t know where you get them from. Theoretically, the mockservice can generate them itself. Or another service that is responsible for those values injects the mockserice and set the values as soon as they are generated. All possible. You have to find out what fits best to your needs.

Comment: I think you've helped me understand what I was trying to accomplish here. I'll give it a go. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear that my support was useful.